# Should [openoffice.org] and [openoffice-api] be merged?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[openoffice.org](/questions/tagged/openoffice.org) - 354 questions, just suggested a wiki excerpt

[openoffice-api](/questions/tagged/openoffice-api) - 2 questions, no wiki

Is there any difference between these two tags? I assume that they are both used for questions related to using the OpenOffice.org API. I suspect that one has just become vastly more popular than the other for some reason, or perhaps that [openoffice-api](/questions/tagged/openoffice-api) is just a newly-created and redundant tag.

If there is no discernible difference then I suggest we merge [openoffice-api](/questions/tagged/openoffice-api) -> [openoffice.org](/questions/tagged/openoffice.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing: as a developer, you could choose the hard route and build a program that complements OpenOffice or uses OpenOffice file formats *without* using their published api.  This indicates to me that perhaps two distinct tags are warranted.

However, I'll hazard a guess that a large number (more than half?) of the current `openoffice.org` questions should really fit under `openoffice-api`.  And given the low number of `openoffice-api` questions, I think the most expedient solution here is to just retag those two questions and be done with it.

Comment: Questions about the file formats would be better tagged [tag:opendocument] (now 21 questions), wouldn't they?